# Creating a calendar event with an alarm using EKEventEditViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, events, alarm

I'm using the following code to create an event, and display a popup asking the user to save the event:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKCalendar *calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.calendar = calendar;
event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event: %@", [self.event title]]; 
event.location = self.event.location;
event.notes = [self stringByStrippingHTML: [self.event description]];
event.startDate = [self.event startDate]; 
event.endDate = [self.event endDate];

NSTimeInterval alarmOffset = -1*60*60;//1 hour
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];

[event addAlarm:alarm];
EKEventEditViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
eventViewController.event = event;
eventViewController.eventStore=eventStore;
eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
```

This works fine except the event alarm property doesn't get set as you can see form the image below:

[image: Alarm Not Set]

If I save the event before showing the view controller it does get the alarm set.

Please note I'm using the LLVM compiler, so don't worry about not releasing stuff!

Ta

Ross

Comment: did you ever solve this?  I don't think this is possible.  I think the best way around it would be create your own editEventController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out how to do it.

Your controller would have to implement the protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate, and set the EKEventEditViewController delegate to self. Then just implement the

`navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

method and add the alarm there.

Here is my implementation.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[EKEventEditViewController class]]) {
      EKEventEditViewController *ek = (EKEventEditViewController*)navigationController;
      EKEvent *event = ek.event;
      // set alarm to 15 mins prior of the event if it starts later than 15 mins out
      if ([event.startDate compare:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*15]] != NSOrderedAscending) { 
        EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60*15*-1];
        event.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];
      }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```m
NSTimeInterval alarmOffset = -1*60*60;//1 hour
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];

[event addAlarm:alarm];
```

Write the above code after presenting the controller i.e after the line

```m
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: how does it make a difference?